# Node JS : Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express

Beginner here. I understand that the below error message occurs when the api tries to set the response more than once. And i also realize the asynchronous characteristics of node js.

But still i am unable to debug the issue. Please help me out.

```
router.route("/new").post((req, res) => {

  //Variable declarations
  sql.open(connectionString, function(err, conn){
    var pm = conn.procedureMgr();
    pm.callproc('dbo.AddRequestDetails',[request_zone,request_type,requester_type,request_flow,
      sales_order,requester_email,quotation,request_reason,request_status,
      StatusFlag, bot_status,bot_comments,additional_notification_to,additional_information, approver,
      old_value,new_value,new_shipping_point,partner_name,text_type,text_type_action,table_data], function(err,results,output){
      console.log("Hi");
        if (err != null) {
        console.log("error",err.message);
        var user =  req.ge('User');
        var scriptName = path.basename(__filename);
        var value = {err: err.message, user: user, scriptName:scriptName};
        axios.post(configData.SERVER_URL + "/api/logToDB", value);
        res.status(400).json(err.message);
      } else {
        console.log("Data successfully added in Main Table & Sub Table");
        res.json("Data successfully added in Main Table & Sub Table");
      }
      
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And my output appears like below.

```
Hi
Data successfully added in Main Table & Sub Table
POST /api/add/new 200 44.882 ms - 51
Hi
Data successfully added in Main Table & Sub Table
_http_outgoing.js:558
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they
are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\C572103\Documents\One
Order Change\OOC Portal\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\C572103\Documents\One Order Change\OOC Portal\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\C572103\Documents\One Order Change\OOC Portal\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at C:\Users\C572103\Documents\One Order Change\OOC Portal\backend\routes\uploadData.js:58:13
    at Object.callback (C:\Users\C572103\Documents\One Order
Change\OOC Portal\backend\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\procedure.js:233:13)
    at onProcedureRaw (C:\Users\C572103\Documents\One Order Change\OOC Portal\backend\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\procedure.js:60:22)
    at C:\Users\C572103\Documents\One Order Change\OOC Portal\backend\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\reader.js:199:15
    at onStatementComplete (C:\Users\C572103\Documents\One Order Change\OOC Portal\backend\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\driver.js:185:11)
    at Object.end (C:\Users\C572103\Documents\One Order Change\OOC Portal\backend\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\driver.js:318:19) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

I am using msnodesqlv8 for sql operations

Comment: It seems you are sending the response twice.

Comment: Yes..looks like it. But i dont seem to understand where and how

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are to set the headers of the response (like res.setHeader(400)) after you send the response, controls the if else statments, seems it enter in an error else after sending 200

Answer (score 0):

It's very obvious from your code that `Hi` is called twice. My guess is that you're opening a new sql connecting using `sql.open`, but you never close it. Even though you send the result to the response, the connection is still opened and some listeners might fire again, even though on another request.

Also check if in a single request `pm.callproc` does only one thing and then does not fire two callbacks, because basically that's the real issue - you try to send two responses for the same request.

Comment: I guess i need not explicitly close the sql.open. The connection is open only within the braces.